# Creating custom list or grid view

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, baseadapter

While creating custom list / grid view I know custom adapters are to be created. I am confused on when to use Array Adapter / Base Adapter in creating custom views.

Comment: what u want to perform chitra??

Comment: Hey shiv,I want to have custom list view with image and some text in it.

Comment: Refer this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: and if thats too hard you can start from here http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/listview-with-images-and-text-using-simple-adapter-in-android/

Comment: hey shiv,actually what my question is to implement custom adapter there are two ways either use base adapter or array adapter. I want to known when to use base & array adapter.

Comment: ArrayAdapter can be used to link say a list of items with an array. The ArrayAdapter works between an your array data and a list item layout to populate a list.

Comment: but we can also achieve same with base adapter

Comment: Base adapter is abstract class where as array adapter and the list adapter are the concrete classses..BaseAdapter is the most customizable, so you can use it for anything (you have to customize it a little bit more than others)

Comment: So we can use either base or array adapter for creating customize views. Depends on our choice.

Comment: In short, you could either use the ready-made ArrayAdapter, or write your own adapter that extends BaseAdapter

Comment: if you got this atleast you can accept or upvote my answer chitra??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android Custom ListView with Image and Text you Can refer this tutorial
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

if you get any problem you can ask here ...

Basically

**ListAdapter**

Extended Adapter that is the bridge between a ListView and the data that backs the list.

**BaseAdaper**

Common base class of common implementation for an Adapter that can be used in both ListView (by implementing the specialized ListAdapter interface} and Spinner (by implementing the specialized SpinnerAdapter interface.

**ArrayAdapter**

A concrete BaseAdapter that is backed by an array of arbitrary objects.

Refer below links

[ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html)

[BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html)

[ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)